# Cleaning the system.log in magento but encountering problems

Tags: magento

I'm getting some errors in my log which I'm having trouble identifying.
Also I'm not very experienced in php/xml yet, but I'm trying my best. I've been google'in alot ot try and find answers on how to trace down the error, but with no luck.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 120: parser error : Premature end of data in tag layout line 29  in /var/www/site.com/../Update.php on line 432
```

And

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string():     &lt;/customer_account&gt;  in /var/www/site.com/../Update.php on line 432
```

As far as I've figured out, it might be due to some error, in one of the XML files? I've been looking through alot of them but without luck.

Comment: Have you done a search for `customer_account` in the xml files? TBH, it looks like an update file for an extension is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a missing

```
</reference>
```

inside a

```
<customer_account>..</customer_account>
```

Seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: next time, 'find' and 'xmllint' (can be found in libxml2-utils on apt-based distros) are your friend! find -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xmllint --noout {} \;

Comment: @ThomasNielsen in Which File?